# Filter and hide specific contacts using Contact.framework iOS

Tags: ios, swift, contacts, import-contacts

I'd want to `filter out contact with only email address` and hide the `phone number only contacts`.

So far I've been able to disable the `phone number only contacts`.

```
    let picker = CNContactPickerViewController()
    picker.predicateForEnablingContact = NSPredicate(format: "emailAddresses.@count > 0")
    picker.delegate = self

    self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```